# Find the namespace of a web resource using its URL

Tags: url, namespaces

**How can we generalize the namespace for a web resource ?**

This is how I am doing it:

The Backus-Naur form of a name in a namespace is:

```
name = <namespace identifier> separator <local name>
```

The template for a Web URL is

```
`scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]`
```

There are different cases that can be considered:

1. URL = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[#fragment]`, namespace = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query]`
2. URL = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path`, namespace = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]pathpart` where `pathpart` is a substring of `path` which contains all characters until and including the last "/" character
3. URL = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query]`, namespace = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path`
4. URL = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]`, namespace = `scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query]`

My questions are:

1. Is the above generalization for a determining the namespace of a web
   resource valid ?
2. Am I missing any cases ?

Thanks

Comment: In which context do you use the term *namespace* here? For what purpose do you need this?

Comment: does the context or purpose can change the definition of a namespace for Web resource ? it's just a question, can this definition not be universal ?